# $\ell^2$ is not locally compact

Tags: compactness, locally-compact-groups

> $\ell^2$ is not locally compact.

How to prove this, I just know the definition of locally compact. I am finding it hard to find any trick. $\ell^2$ is the sequence of all square summable sequences. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

"Locally compact" means every point has an open neighborhood whose closure is compact. What does an open neighborhood of $\mathbf 0 =(0,0,0,\ldots)\in\ell^2$ look like? This is a metric space, so every open neighborhood $G$ of $\mathbf 0$ must include some open ball centered at $\mathbf 0.$ Let $r$ be the radius of such an open ball. Then the points $ x_k = \Big( \quad \ldots0,0,0,\underbrace{\quad\dfrac r 2, \quad}_{\large k\text{th component}} 0,0,0, \ldots \quad \Big)$ for $k=1,2,3,\ldots$ are all within the open neighborhood $G$. If the closure of $G$ is compact, then so is every closed subset of the closure of $G$, including $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots\}.$

Cover the set $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots\}$ with open balls of radius $r/2,$ one centered at each of $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots.$ There can be no finite subcover, because each of the open balls of radius $r/2$ about the points $x_k$ can cover only one of $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots$, since the distance between any two of $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots$ is $r/\sqrt2 > r/2.$

Comment: What argument could I use to say $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots\}$ is closed?

Comment: @edamondo : It is closed if it contains all of its limit points, and it does, since it has no limit points. Or you can say it is closed because its complement is open. Just let $y$ be some point not in that set and think about finding an open ball centered at $y$ that does not contain any of the points in this set in question.

Answer (score 2):

you need to show that closed balls are not compact. For simplicity you can show Unit closed ball is not compact. Take the sequence $\{e_n\}$ then $ \|e_n  - e_m\|^2 = 2$ for all distinct natural numbers $m$ and $n$. Therefore $\{ e_n \}$ does not contain any convergent subsequence.

Note that your claim is even true for any normed space.

Comment: Well, not just *any* normed space. $\Bbb R^2$ happens to be locally compact

Comment: You never gave a definition of $e_n$.

Comment: Oh Yes I was dummy!!  actually any infinite dimensional normed space!   I have tendency to think about infinite Dimensions when talking about Normed spaces ....

Comment: @MichaelHardy   Since the vector $e_n$  is a standard notation in Hilbert spaces, readers will understand what I mean by that .

Comment: @nonlinearthought : Perhaps, but how did you conclude that $\|e_n-e_m\|=1\text{?}$ If $\|e_n\| = \|e_m\| = 1$ and $\langle e_n,e_m\rangle =0$ then you have $\|e_n-e_m\| = \sqrt 2. \qquad$

Comment: you're right.  I will correct it. Thanks!

Comment: Why is it enough to show that closed balls are not compact

Comment: @mathisfun since every open neighborhood  contains open balls. + If the closure an open set is compact it implies that the closure of its contained open balls (which are closed ball)  must be compact too.

Comment: I did not get it after + .please again say it clearly.I am missing something.

Comment: @mathisfun   Try to prove this simple lemma, then you will get what I wrote.

Let $X$ be a metric space then, $X$ is locally compact if and only if for any $x \in X$ there exist open ball centered $x$ whose closure is compact.